# How to dynamically update a modal window's contents with HTML elements from sections using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop, iteration

I'm working on a timeline type app / page and would like a modal window to open with each timeline block's contents when "Read More" is clicked.  However, I seem to be lost in the iteration phase as whenever I click on "Read More" only the last section's title shows up in the modal title.  Which means the loop finishes iterating and populates the modal title with the last element. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

**Edited full program down to a more digestible format(hopefully) **

```js
//select modal interaction 
var readBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("cd-read-more");
var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".closeBtn");
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var modalTitle = document.getElementById("modal-title");
var modalBody = document.querySelector(".modal-body");
var contentBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("cd-timeline-block")
var timeline = [];

//select cd-timeline-content 
timeline.postTitles = document.getElementsByClassName("post-title");
timeline.postBody = document.getElementsByClassName("post-body");
timeline.postImg = document.getElementsByClassName("pic");

//modal event functions
function openModal(indexNumber) {
  for (var i = 0; i < readBtn.length; i++) {
    modalTitle.innerHTML = timeline.postTitles[i].innerHTML;
  }
  modal.style.display = "block";
};


//event listeners for selections
//loop thru collection of readBtn array and call openModal to each
for (var i = 0; i < readBtn.length; i++) {
  readBtn[i].addEventListener("click", openModal);
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Example Timeline</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Example Timeline</h1>
  </header>

  <section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">
    <div class="cd-timeline-block">
      <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-location">
        <img src="img/cd-icon-location.svg" alt="Picture">
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

      <div class="cd-timeline-content">
        <div class="post-title">
          <h2>First Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="post-body">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
        <span class="cd-date">July 17 2017</span>
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 id="modal-title"><span class="closeBtn">&times;</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <h4>Test Footer</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END MODAL -->
```

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... **don't just copy in your entire program!**

Comment: ^ Even though I agree that there's a lot of code here, and a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help... I do have to commend you for **clearly** showcasing your problem, mentioning your constraints and adding a Stack Snippet on your very first post. I'd also recommend checking out the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: And the problem is that you're not actually passing your `index` to your `openModal` function in `readBtn[i].addEventListener("click", openModal)`. You're looking to add a **closure** :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I was probably a little rude with my comment. I apologize OP.

Comment: No offense taken.  Thank you!  I'm going to have to do a bit more researching closures as per Obsidian Age.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input and clues.  Out of frustration I wound up using jQuery instead of vanilla JS.  I will transpile (am I using it correctly?) it into vanilla JS as a reinforcement exercise but I just wanted the functionality for now.

For reference this is the code I wound up with:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //set click function on read more button
 $(".cd-timeline-block").on("click", function(){
  //selects modal title and empties of content
  $(".modal-title").empty();
  // //select modal body and empties it
  $(".modal-body").empty();
  //set variable title as click selector
  var title = $(".post-title", this);
  //set variable body content as click selections body
  var body = $(".post-body", this);
  $(title).clone().appendTo(".modal-title");
  $(body).clone().appendTo(".modal-body");
 })
});
```